# Laravel API + Vue.js or Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've seen some tutorials about Full stack development with Laravel, however there is this one guy who made two projects. One for Laravel as API and other one a full fledged Vue.js project generated with a command and connected to his Laravel API. I'm wondering, what does this approach makes it better or worse than one big project made with Laravel for both frontend (Laravel Blade) and backend? When should I go for Vue project connected and Laravel API or for Laravel with Blade?

Comment: The frontend can be as complicated as the backend, so using some Vue features can save so much time to implement and maintain the project as a whole, sure you can make the same thing with Laravel it all depend on needs and tasks that app should comply.

Answer (score 2):

It purely depends on one's project requirement.

Youtube vidoes are tutorials and they should be acknowledged only for guidance and I would resist in making a decision based on youtube videos.

I would suggest you to list your project requirement and try to find all the possibilities and weight the pros and cons.

The Learning curve for both the framework in not high as far as if you are well versed with Javascript and php.

Choose your stack wisely. Coz once you start working on it you will be investing your time and going back in search for a new stack wouldn't be a good decision.

***for eg:***
My preference..

For an ecommerce platform..

I would use `Vue.js + Laravel api for front end` where as `blade for backend`

But you could develop it either way..

All it matters is what suits you and how comfortable are you with the frameworks..

Answer (score 0):

I know both frameworks well. The question is, what does your project need? And what role plays Laravel in this context? You know it's totally possible to make a full website, even a very complex one with just vue.js alone. The few cases when you need a backend is when you need to send emails, upload and process files or having a database - well you can skipp even that if you use Firebase for storage and it offers you nodejs functionality that can be executed in their cloud and authentication.

The most natural stack would be vue and node (backend) as both use javascript.
Personaly I use Vuejs + [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com)  + [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and sometimes [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/).